# Copy individual rows to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, function, copy-paste

I'm not very confident with VBA yet - but I feel very close for this function.

I'm trying to write a script to copy rows from one sheet ('search') over to a different sheet ('order'). For example, the whole row from column A to M, if the value in column M has a value in it over 0.

I want it to pull over multiple rows, if there are multiple with a value in M over 0, and also only onto the next free line in the destination sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub CopySomeCells()
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRow As Long
    Dim DestinationRow As Long

    Set SourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search")
    Set DestinationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Order")

    DestinationRow = DestinationSheet.Cells(DestinationSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For SourceRow = 2 To SourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If SourceSheet.Range("M" & SourceRow).Value > 0 Then
            SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(SourceRow, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(SourceRow, 29)).Copy _
                DestinationSheet.Cells(DestinationRow, 2)
            DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1
        End If
    Next SourceRow
    Range("M2:M7000").Clear
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue that you encountered?

Comment: You might consider using `Range.AutoFilter` (applying a filter for rows with a value greater than 0), and then copying the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`, instead of looping row by row.

Comment: `DestinationRow = DestinationSheet.Cells(DestinationSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` will set the `DestinationRow` to the last non-blank row of the sheet. Meaning the copy will *overwrite* the last row of the `DestinationSheet`. Add a +1 to `DestinationRow` so that it moves to the row below the last non-blank row.

Comment: Is the code in the workbook where these worksheets are located? Column `29` is column `AC`, column `13` is column `M`. So what do you want to copy? You can fix the 'row issue' mentioned by Toddleson by moving `DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1` above the `SourceSheet...` line.

Comment: @Toddleson apologies I forgot to put the issue! The issue I'm having is the 'if' doesn't seem to be working.  It is pulling through the top line in the source sheet, regardless if there is a value is column M. i.e. If I have a value in row 10 and 15 (in column M) - I want it to pull the whole line of 10 and 15 over. Currently it is pulling in line 2 and 3 .